# What is the origin of "dead end" on a road sign?

Tags: etymology

Unless one has grown up with it, I cannot see that the intent of "dead end" on a road sign is at all obvious. The oft-used alternative "no outlet" at least means what it says. And while a non-native English speaker might have difficulty with "no outlet" I suspect that it could be looked up in an English-to-x dictionary, but "dead end"? I think not. So why did "dead end" come to mean that the end of a road is imminent?

Comment: No outlet and dead end don't mean the same thing. No outlet means that you can't get back to the main road by continuing in this direction. Dead end means there are no more turns off this road.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dead+end&searchmode=none

Answer (score 6):

*OED 1 s.v.* **Dead** D.2. gives a first citation of the phrase in 1886, with respect to closed water pipes, and in 1889 with a sense approximating the ordinary modern use: "G. Findlay *Eng.Railway* 199 This is what is termed a 'dead-end' warehouse .. the waggons come in and go out the same way, and cannot be taken through the warehouse."

The definition offered here is "a closed end of a water-pipe, passage, etc., through which there is no way." This evidently derives from *ibid.* "IV. Without motion (relatively or absolutely)".

I trust that the metaphorical extension of *dead* is obvious. We speak of *dead* air, *dead* water, *dead* calm, a *dead* stop; a wire is *live* if it carries a current, *dead* if it does not. The *dead* center of a rotating object is the axis point about which it revolves, at which there is no motion. *Dead* weight is the weight of an inert, *i.e.* unmoving body. A *deadlock* is a struggle in which neither party can 'move' the other.

So a *dead end* street is one through which traffic cannot move.

Comment: Although the engineering term from the same era is 'blind' as in blind hole, blind rivet and we have "blind alley" rather than dead-alley

Comment: @mgb fersher. Any base term can be productive of metaphor - which very quickly becomes (in a different sense) 'dead metaphor'. . . Oh, and against your 'blind rivet' I left out 'deadbolt'.

Comment: interesting that not being able to see/go through is 'blind' in a hole and alley but "dead-end" not "blind-end". Dead in all the other meanings makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'dead-end' may have originated during the time of ancient Rome in which streets were planned for defense purposes. If an enemy entered a 'dead-end' street, they would be trapped with no escape, and would be easy targets for defending troops. Leon Battista Alberti writes during the 15th century that

> “The Ancients in All Towns were for having some intricate Ways and turn again Streets [i.e.dead-ends or loops], without any Passage through them, that if an Enemy comes into them, he may be at a Loss, and be in Confusion and Suspense; or if he pushes on daringly, may be easily destroyed

See Leon Battista Alberti, Ten Books on Architecture, 1485, ed. James Rykwert(New York: Transatlantic Arts, 1966) Book IV, Ch. V. 75 [cited on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac#cite_note-1).

Comment: The concept of a "dead-end" street is different from the use of the term "dead-end" to describe them.